# How to unit test dataframe operation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a function:

```
def example(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    
    return (df - df.mean()) / df.std()
```

For example a test case can be: I create a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1], [4], [7]]),
                   columns=['a'])
print(df)
   a
0  1
1  4
2  7

print(example(df))
     a
0 -1.0
1  0.0
2  1.0
```

This is what I tried:

```
class testExample(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_valid_inputs(self):
        test_df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'test': [1, 4, 7]})
        expected_result_1 = pd.Series([-1.0, 0.0, 1.0])
        pd.testing.assert_series_equal(xxx.example(test_df_1), expected_result_1, check_names=False)
```

this gave me error `AssertionError: Series Expected type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>, found <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> instead` I tried a few different other things but not working...

Comment: It's not clear to me what part of this you are stuck on. You have a good example unit test there - create a dataframe, pass it to `example`, and check that what's returned is what you expected.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Teach me this body of technique” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Check out [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/) for good patterns for unit testing.

Comment: Pandas has a lot of tests built into the library: I.e. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.3/pandas/tests/arithmetic/test_numeric.py. But what you have is a good start. Basically take a small example you know works, check some features about it (i.e. an exact output) and then expand to capture all edge cases.

Comment: See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  The practice of unit testing is covered quite thoroughly in existing resources.  How to use a particular package is covered in their documentation.  We expect you to include that learning in your post.

Comment: I've just updated what I have tried (code + error), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly a matter of taste, but I prefere using the special `setUp` method to initialize the data. It can then be shared by more than one test method. Here I would use:

```
class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        """Initialize a dataframe for the tests"""
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1], [4], [7]]),
                               columns=['a'])

    def testExample(self):
        """Control the result of the example function"""
        result = example(self.df)
        self.assertEqual([-1.0, 0, 1.0], result['a'].to_list())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```